# Запуск программы через иконку

Tags: c#, winforms

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Environment.CurrentDirectory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory; 
            AutoRun(); 
            Application.Run(new Worker());
        }
        static void AutoRun()
        {
            RegistryKey myKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run\\",true);
            myKey.SetValue("StudyIcon", Application.ExecutablePath);
        }
    }
    class Worker : ApplicationContext
    {
        private static NotifyIcon icon;
        public Worker()
        {
            icon = new NotifyIcon(); 
            icon.Icon = new Icon("icon.ico"); 
            icon.Text = "Test";
            icon.Visible = true; 
            icon.Click += OnClickIcon; 
            icon.MouseMove += OnEnterIcon;
            this.ThreadExit += OnExit; 
        }
        private void OnClickIcon(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.ExitThread(); // когда кликаете на иконку, то программа выключается.
        }
        private void OnExit(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            icon.Dispose();// выключаем иконку, чтобы не осталась на панели задач
        }
}
```

Как сделать, что бы запихнуть запуск программы в private void OnClickIcon

Comment: Вообще не понятно что ты пытаешься сделать. Или это какой-то велосипед?

Comment: То есть Вы хотите иметь иконку и при клике чтобы запускалась Ваша программа?

Comment: Чтобы программы при закрытии сворачивалась в иконку в панель задач (правый нижний угол) и при нажанитии на нее снова откривалась а у меня при нажатии  закрывается полностю

Comment: Так добавьте одну переменную bool Visible, которая при открытии будет истина, а при закрытии станет ложь и проверяйте.
Приложение консольное?

Comment: @IgorIlyichyov Windows Form

Comment: Если вам нужно _сворачивание_ и _разворачивание_ (вообще, это называется _минимазация_ и _максимизация_) окна, то так и напишите. _Запуск_ и _выключение_ - это совсем другое.

Comment: @IgorIlyichyov ваш код вставить в program.cs?

Comment: Замените на свое, тут главное не вставить, а понять принцип работы, это обязательно.

Comment: @IgorIlyichyov что такое WindowState?

Comment: Статус окна формы, в каком она состоянии: свернута, развернута, максимизирована

Answer (score 3):

```
private void Form_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     notifyIcon1.BalloonTipTitle = "Minimize to Tray App";
     notifyIcon1.BalloonTipText = "You have successfully minimized your form.";

     if (FormWindowState.Minimized == this.WindowState)
     {
          notifyIcon1.Visible = true;
          notifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(500);
          this.Hide();    
     }
     else if (FormWindowState.Normal == this.WindowState)
     {
          notifyIcon1.Visible = false;
     }
}

private void notifyIcon1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
     this.Show();
     this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
}
```